# How to connect React Js to mysql with node js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

I get a problem when connecting ReactJs to mysql with nodejs.
This is my complete code.

This is my React file, 'member.js', running on port 3000.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Member extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { player: {} };
    this.onSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = this;

    fetch('/player', {
      method: 'GET',
      data: {
        number: self.refs.number,
        name: self.refs.name,
        position: self.refs.position
      }
    }).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      }).then(function(body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="member-page">
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Number" ref="number" />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Name" ref="name" />
          <input type="text" placeholder="Position" ref="position" />
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default Member;
```

and this is my node file, 'player.js', running on port 4000.

```
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); 

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "react_1"
});

app.post('/player', function(req, res) {

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");

  // Get sent data.
  var player = req.body;
  // Do a MySQL query.
  var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO player VALUES ?', player, function(err, result) {
    // Neat!
  });
  res.end('Success');
});

app.listen(4000, function() {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 4000!');
});
```

when I try to input data I get error like this 'Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0', I don't know why, 2 days again I must show this duty to my lecture, please anyone help me to solve this problem.

thank you very much.

Comment: Please post the code as block and not as a picture then we can help

Comment: Thanks, I have changed from picture to block code. @ShubhamJain

Comment: You are making call to get method and in your player.js you dont have any get method you have post method?? Is it a typo?

Answer (score 0):

First, where you getting that error ?

Then, could you try to add quote to your react script when you constructing the JSON payload

```
data : {
    "number" : self.refs.number,
    "name" : self.refs.name,
    "position" : self.refs.position,
}
```

Then, make sure you set Content-Type on the header as application/json :

> 'Content-Type': 'application/json'